# how to send the firebase token at the django backend with vue?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

i can't send the firebase token to the backend, i thought the problem was that the function was not asynchronous but it still didn't work for me, please i need help, thanks!

```
user.getIdToken(true)
     .then(function(idToken) {
           const path = 'http://localhost:8000/api/google-login'
           console.log(idToken)
           axios.post(path , idToken)
                  .then((response) => { 
                      console.log('anda o no anda')                              
                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                      console.log(error);
                             });
      }).catch(function(error) {
               console.log(error)
      });
```

the error in console.
POST http: // localhost: 8000 / api / google-login 500 (Internal Server Error)
but if I copy the idtoken and send it manually to the backend it works.

Comment: May you post the full logs of the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it now, you were sending the token without your key

'''
axios.post(path , {'token_id':idToken})
'''